# Linkedin authentication showing blank screen on 2nd step verification in android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, authorization, linkedin-api

I have integrated *Linkedin* in my android app using *OAuth 2.0*. But when testing using *LinkedIn* test accounts which are frequently used on different devices, due to 2-step verification process, on the second screen, it's showing blank screen with just a *LinkedIn* logo on top.

I am using webview to display *LinkedIn*. On older devices, the second screen for entering verification key is showing correctly, but it's not showing devices with Os < 4.4.

This issue occurs only using test accounts, and authentication using normal accounts are working seamlessly.

I doubt if it is causing due to some issue in the webview, but can't find a solution to it.

[image: First authentication screnn]

[image: Error screen (2nd screen)]